# Spring @PathVariable integration test

Tags: spring, testing, spring-mvc, mocking, integration-testing

I'm trying ot write an integration test for one of my methods, that handles a form submission.
The problem is that i use `@PathVariable int id` in the `@RequestMapping` of my controller.
I get the following error message when my test method reaches the .handle() part.

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [id] in @RequestMapping
```

So the controller cant reach the id. I'm using `request.setRequestURI("/url-" + s.getId());` But appareantly its not helping with setting up `@PathVariable`.
Is there any way to set up the `@PathVariable` of my Mock object?

Update:

Yeah, im useing `MockHttpServletRequest` and `annotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle` in my test class.

The Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"edit" })    
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("sceneryEditForm") SceneryEditForm s,
            @PathVariable int id, Model model) {
       // some code that useing id
}
```

The test method:

```
@Test
public void testEditButton() throws Exception {
        MyObject s = new MyObject();
        request.setMethod("POST");
        request.setRequestURI("/edit-" + s.getId());
        request.setParameter("edit", "set");
        final ModelAndView mav = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter()
                                       .handle(request, response, controller);  
        assertViewName(mav, "redirect:/view-" + s.getId()); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of your method (the source one, not the test)?

Comment: Please post your contoller and your test.  I assume you are using a MockHttpServletRequest and annotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle in your test.

Comment: i have updated the question with the sample codes, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct: there is no path variable `id`

You need to add the path expression with an placeholder `id`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something/{id}",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                params = {"edit" })
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("sceneryEditForm") SceneryEditForm s,
        @PathVariable int id, Model model) {
   // some code that useing id
}
```